# How to count Number of characters without any Special characters?

Tags: python

I have a txt data. Know i would like to count the characters without any Special characters like ". , ; ! or :". How can I do that?

After that i would like to count the longest wort in the txt data without including any Special characters. I'm completly new in python.

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: Why without any library? Is it an assignment?

Comment: I don't understand the question very well: do you want to process the entire text as a whole large string, or first you want to split it in "words" and then proceed to count the characters? Try to elaborate a little more. In the mean time, I suggest you to look for tutorials regarding "regular expressions" in python. I think with a little bit of effort you will quickly find what you need

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression:

```
import re

text_data = "Hello, World! Whazzzupp?"
re.findall(r"\w+", text_data)
# ['Hello', 'World', 'Whazzzupp']
```

`\w+` means 1 or more alphanumeric characters.

Answer (score 0):

Without any library in O(n) it would be something like that:

```
special_char = {"." ,"," ,";" ,"!"}
with open('data.txt') as data:
    text_data= data.read()
print('Characters number:', len([c for c in text_data if c not in special_char ]))
word_lens = {len(w): "".join(c for c in w if c.isalpha()) for w in text_data.split()}
print(sorted(word_lens))
```

Comment: 1) This is only half the question, and 2) there are more special characters.  Perhaps a more robust solution is required.

Comment: Might be better to have a whitelist than a blacklist ;)

Comment: @S3DEV I missed the second part, added for it as well, could do both in same time, but want sure if a care about spaces....and yap, I also showed an option with `islapha()` @
mozway